# Excel - Use Column C to Sum all values in Column A since the last time that Column B was a "Yes"

Tags: excel, sum, instance

Image is attached of what I am trying to do.

[image]

I am able to accomplish this with the following formula:

=IF(AND(B1="Y",B2="Y"),$A1,IF(AND(B1="Y",B3="Y"),SUM($A1:$A2),IF(AND(...etc.

The issue is that there are 50 rows of data to go through and I want something that is easier to be repeated where someone can duplicate this without having to hard enter the same formula 50 times for row 1 and 49 times for row 2 and 48 times for row 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> <sub>there are 50 rows of data to go through</sub>

I've used row 55 as the absolute cut-off for values in column B.

```
=IF(B2="Y", SUM(A2:INDEX(A:A, IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(B3:B$55)/(B3:B$55="Y"), 1)-1, 55))), 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Breaking this down, the ROW(B3:B$55)/(B3:B$55="Y") seems to be an issue. Performing each of them separately, ROW(B3:B$55) returns a value of 3. If B3 is changed to B4 then a value of 4 is returned, B5 gives a value of 5 and so on. (B3:B$55="Y") returns FALSE. What is supposed to be the function of these two parts of the equation and am I missing something?

Comment: If it helps with being exact in the formula, the columns Delta, Y/N, and Duration are col I, col J, and col K respectively, and they are located on row 4.